# Store objects using ehcache +Spring

Tags: spring, ehcache

My application has internationalization for all tables. So all tables has its another table for different languange support with key as language code like 'en-us'. Every time if it hits the db and to show in page then applications get slow. so We implemented by extending AbstractMessageSource class.I referred the link http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=15223 But based on this stored all the messages are stored in the memory. if table size/number of table grows this mesage hash also grows. then memory problem comes. So we have planned to keep it in disk using ehcache technique. Please provide me the sample. Let me know is this valid option to store the objects?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Map entries in DataSourceMessageSource to:

/** Cache holding already generated MessageFormats per message code and Locale 
   * Map

/** all messages (for all basenames) per locale 
   * Map

That will get you going. You also need an ehcache.xml with cache entries for each of the above. You should speicfy overflowToDisk=true.

Note that you will incur a deserialization cost. If you are seeing a high cost in cpu doing that it might be worth restructuring the code to return what you want speficically rather than a map.

Greg Luck